# High rep users should be able to add and remove post notices

Tags: feature-request, post-notice, privileges

As you know we use a lot of post notices on this site. I think they are very useful and work very well, but only moderators can add and remove them.

I see no reason why that should be the case.

I propose that 15k users (in other words, users that can protect questions) should be able to add and remove post notices.

Does the community agree? Should there be a vote of 3 users? No vote?

Should there be a mechanism similar to question protection where only the user who adds a notice can remove it?

Comment: I suggested something similar in connection with a review queue for "citation needed" posts (http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/add-a-review-queue-for-posts-with-a-citation-needed-notice)

Comment: Great proposal! It'd be interesting to extend it to all sites.

Comment: Would a proposal be more visible to developers on meta.stackoverflow, or is it the same?

Comment: @gerrit it is the same, although putting in on meta.so may get more votes.

Comment: I agree but I think the cut off should be 35K not 15K.